# POSIX regex ignore non-ascii character?

Tags: regex

I want to check whether a string contains `|c`, but some non-ascii characters are making trouble as the following code returns `Match`. Is there a way to ignore non-ascii characters?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        regex_t regex;
        int reti;
        char msgbuf[100];

/* Compile regular expression */
        reti = regcomp(&regex, "\|c", REG_EXTENDED);
        if( reti ){ fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n"); exit(1); }

/* Execute regular expression */
        reti = regexec(&regex, "<81>U¼T_<84>Ùe/^P^Rï+ß¶ë", 0, NULL, 0);
        if( !reti ){
                puts("Match");
        }
        else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){
                puts("No match");
        }
        else{
                regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
                fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
                exit(1);
        }

/* Free compiled regular expression if you want to use the regex_t again */
  regfree(&regex);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

non-ASCII characters in the input aren't the problem. Instead, `"\|c"` is a wrong way of writing `"|c"` (which matches everything). Use *two* backslashes (one to escape the backslash in the string itself):

```
    reti = regcomp(&regex, "\\|c", REG_EXTENDED);
```